# Write a Python formatted generator

Tags: python, io, generator

To generate a **Tecplot** file I use:

```
import numpy as np

x, y = np.genfromtxt('./files.dat', unpack=True)
nb_value = x.size
x_splitted = np.split(x, nb_value // 1000 + 1)
y_splitted = np.split(y, nb_value // 1000 + 1)

with open('./test.dat', 'w') as f:
    f.write('TITLE = \" YOUPI \" \n')
    f.write('VARIABLES = \"x\" \"Y\"  \n')
    f.write('ZONE T = \"zone1 \" , I=' + str(nb_value) + ', F=BLOCK  \n')
    for idx in range(len(x_splitted)):
        string_list = ["%.7E" % val for val in x_splitted[idx]]
        f.write('\t'.join(string_list)+'\n')
    for idx in range(len(y_splitted)):
        string_list = ["%.7E" % val for val in y_splitted[idx]]
        f.write('\t'.join(string_list)+'\n')
```

Here is an example of `file.dat`:

```
-6.491083147394967334e-02 6.917197804459292456e+02
-6.489978349202699115e-02 6.871829941905543819e+02
-6.481115367048655151e-02 6.707292800160890920e+02
-6.479991205404790622e-02 6.756112033303363660e+02
-6.471117816968344205e-02 7.666798999627604871e+02
-6.469995628177811764e-02 7.819675271405360490e+02
```

This code is working but I have seen that I should use `.format()` instead of `%`. This is running: `string_list = ["{}".format(list(val for val in y_splitted[idx]))]` but won't work with **Tecplot** because we need `7E`.

If I try: `string_list = ["{.7E}".format(list(val for val in y_splitted[idx]))]` it doesn't work at all. I got: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '7E'`

What would be the best way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: @freakish: looks like you misunderstood what `%.7E` does in string formatting operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting specifiers come after a `:` colon:

```
["{:.7E}".format(val) for val in y_splitted[idx]]
```

Note that I had to adjust your list comprehension syntax as well; you only want to apply each `val` to `str.format()`, not the whole loop. In essence, you only needed to replace the `"%.7E" % val` part here.

See the [*Format String Syntax* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

> ```
> replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
> ```

Demo:

```
>>> ["%.7E" % val for val in (2.8, 4.2e5)]
['2.8000000E+00', '4.2000000E+05']
>>> ["{:.7E}".format(val) for val in (2.8, 4.2e5)]
['2.8000000E+00', '4.2000000E+05']
```

Not that you really need to use `str.format()` since there is there are no other parts to the string; if all you have is `"{:<formatspec>}"`, just use the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) and pass in the `<formatspec>` as the second argument:

```
[format(val, ".7E") for val in y_splitted[idx]]
```

Note that in Python, you generally don't loop over a `range()` then use the index to get a list value. Just loop over the list *directly*:

```
for xsplit in x_splitted:
    string_list = [format(val, ".7E") for val in xsplit]
    f.write('\t'.join(string_list) + '\n')
for ysplit in y_splitted:
    string_list = [format(val, ".7E") for val in ysplit]
    f.write('\t'.join(string_list)+'\n')
```

You also don't have to escape the `"` characters in your strings; you only need to do that when the *string delimiters* are also `"` characters; you are using `'` instead. You can use `str.format()` to insert the `nb_value` there too:

```
f.write('TITLE = " YOUPI " \n')
f.write('VARIABLES = "x" "Y"  \n')
f.write('ZONE T = "zone1 " , I={}, F=BLOCK  \n'.format(nb_value))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martijn! Very clear and instructive answer. A last thing, someone told me about `map` for string listing as it is more efficient but I don't see how to use the specifier here: `map(str(format='%.7e',??),??)`

Comment: @Y0da; you can't use `map()` here; using a list comprehension is the better option.

Comment: Thank you got it :)